# Functions returns error about overloading operator

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

This code when I assign the parameter alpha to the function implementation it displays the error Could not find a an overload for '/' that accepts the supplied arguments, but if i set alpha to 1.0 the error disappears.

What could be causing this?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIColor {

  enum AlphaLevel :CGFloat {
    case Empty  = 0.0
    case Low    = 0.25
    case Half   = 0.5
    case High   = 0.75
    case Full   = 1.0
  }

  class func hazeColor(alpha :AlphaLevel = .Full) -> UIColor! {
    return UIColor(red: 230/255.0, green: 235/255.0, blue: 245/255.0, alpha: alpha)
  }

}
```

I'm enlisting the attempts I've tried:

```
class func hazeColor(alpha :AlphaLevel = .Full) -> UIColor! {
    return UIColor(red: Float(230)/255.0, green: Float(235)/255.0, blue: Float(245)/255.0, alpha: alpha)
  }
```

Comment: The float conversion doesn't seem to have been the problem, although if i remove all the '/' instead I get the error: Could not find a an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be OK to use `230/255.0`, because the type of the number will be determined after the calculation. If you assign the two number to a variable (or constant), you will be have to convert them before calculating. So there is no problem in the `230/255.0`. (And in fact, `CGFloat` is a `Double`..not a `Float`)

It seems there is a fatal bug for me to define the `AlphaLevel` enum in the extension of `UIColor`. Swift will crash if I do so (although it should be possible). Anyway...

The problem in your code is the `alpha` you passed into the `hazeColor` method is a enum of `AlphaLevel`, instead of `CGFloat`, so the type check failed. Just modify the `UIColor(red: 230/255.0, green: 235/255.0, blue: 245/255.0, alpha: alpha)` to `UIColor(red: 230/255.0, green: 235/255.0, blue: 245/255.0, alpha: alpha.toRaw())`, you can get around.